# compare elements between two lists and print in series

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy, series

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [9, 8, 3, 6, 5]
>>> set(a) & set(b)
{3,5}
```

I am using this code to find matching elements between the lists `a` and `b`, but I want to return list `b` if the elements of `a` match list `b` and output should be in the form of series.

Comment: Please post the desired output.

Comment: output should be presented as series

Comment: You want the output to be in a file or in console?

Comment: anything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of your desired output, you can do this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 3, 6, 5]
b = list(set(a) & set(b))

print("%s%9s" % ('a', 'b'))
print("-" * 10)
for i in a:
    print("%i%4s" % (i,"|"), end="")
    if i in b:
        print("%5i" % (i), end="")
    print()
```

Output:

```
a        b
----------
1   |
2   |
3   |    3
4   |
5   |    5
```

**Edit**

If you want to check if all elements of list `b` are found in list `a`, you can use the `issubset()` function of `set`. Following is an example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3]

if set(b).issubset(a):
    print("b = ", end="")
    print(b)
```

This will print:

```
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thanks. additionally if I have 2 lists and want to write condition such that if  all element in list 2 found in list 1 then it should print list 1 , how can i write code for that?   for exp:- List_1=[1,2,3,4] List_2 =  [2,3,5,6] then if all elemts of List_1 found in List_2 then it should print List_1[1,2,3,4] (i.e list_1)

Comment: Edited my answer, you can take a look and let me know.

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept as answer if it helped you.